# Generating a new list according to the values of the elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

I want to use the command Permute to arrange the rows of a matrix. What I am looking to do is given a list I want to generate a new list which gives me the positions of the elements of the first list according to their values. That is, if there is a list $\{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\}$ such that $p_2>p_3>p_4>p_1$ then I would want a list $\{4,1,2,3\}$. For example: I have a list $\{2,1,3,0\}$ which I want to convert into $\{2,3,1,4\}$ so that I could arrange the rows of the matrix according to the latter list.

Comment: I do not understand what is "the positions of the elements of the first list according to their values".

Comment: It means if there is a list $\{p1,p2,p3,p4\}$ such that $p2>p3>p4>p1$ then I would want a list $\{4,1,2,3\}$. @Szabolcs

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `Ordering`: `Reverse@Ordering[{2, 1, 3, 0}]` is `{3, 1, 2, 4}`.

Comment: Please edit clarifications into the question instead of adding them in comments.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want:

- Decreasing order, not increasing.  We need `Reverse`.
- The inverse permutation of the result of `Ordering`. We need an extra `Ordering` to invert it.

```
a = {2, 1, 3, 0}
(* {2, 1, 3, 0} *)

result = Ordering@Reverse@Ordering[a]
(* {2, 3, 1, 4} *)
```

The question would have been much easier to understand if it is *also* stated in precise terms rather than just an example. For example, you could have said that you needed

```
ReverseSort[a][[result]] === a
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. @Szabolcs